# Upper bound of the fraction of Gamma functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, asymptotics, special-functions, gamma-function

Is there a simple upper bound of the following fraction of Gamma functions for any $a,b\geq1/2$:
$$\left(\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{a\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\right)^{1/a}$$
An upper bound in the following form is enough: there exists a constant $C>0$ and a function $f(a,b)$ such that:
$$\left(\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{a\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\right)^{1/a}\leq C\cdot f(a,b), \forall a,b\geq1/2$$

I have a guess of $f$, which is $\frac{a+b}{a}$. Is it true?

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}$

The inequality in question trivially holds if e.g. $C=1$ and $f(a,b)$ equals the left-hand side of the inequality.

More informatively, the bound with $f(a,b)=\frac{a+b}a$ indeed holds: 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\Ga(a+b)}{a\Ga(a)\Ga(b)}\le C^a\Big(\frac{a+b}a\Big)^a
\end{equation}
for some real $C>0$ and all $a,b\ge1/2$. Indeed, by [Stirling's formula for the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), 
\begin{equation}
 \Ga(x)\asymp\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\Big(\frac xe\Big)^x
\end{equation}
for $x\ge1/2$, where $\asymp$ means "equals up to a universal positive constant factor". So, 
\begin{multline}
 \frac{\Ga(a+b)}{a\Ga(a)\Ga(b)}\asymp\frac1a\,\sqrt{\frac{ab}{a+b}}\frac{(a+b)^{a+b}}{a^a b^b}
 \ll \Big(\frac{a+b}a\Big)^a \Big(\frac{a+b}b\Big)^b \\ 
 = \Big(\frac{a+b}a\Big)^a \Big(1+\frac ab\Big)^b
 < e^a\Big(\frac{a+b}a\Big)^a   
\end{multline}
for $a,b\ge1/2$.

Comment: Shouldn't $\Gamma(x)\asymp\sqrt{x}(x/e)^x$?

Comment: @neverevernever : No, it is as I wrote. You may be confusing it with the Stirling formula for $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$. I have added the reference to Stirling's formula; see the last displayed formula in Section "Stirling's formula for the gamma function" there.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: Is it possible to find an actual constant C?

Comment: @user124297 : Yes, I think it is possible. You may want to post this as a separate question.